# Getting smart card serial number SCardGetAttrib returns error 50

Tags: c#, smartcard, winscard

I am using ACS-ACR88 smart card reader. I am trying to read Smart Card serial number using `SCardGetAttrib` function in `Winscard.dll`, but it always returns error 50. 50 is not defined at [Smart Card Return Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/authentication-return-values). Error 50 is 0x32, and it could be `ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED`.

I looked for what possibly it means, and found that it could mean the driver of the card reader! Here is a link of the answer: [Re: SCardGetAttrib, SERIAL_NO, error 50](http://marc.info/?l=ms-smartcardsdk&m=103430435428137&w=2).

I have updated the driver with no luck. Here's what I've done so far:

```cs
private static UInt32 SCardAttrValue(UInt32 attrClass, UInt32 val)
{
    return (attrClass) * (2 << 16) | val;
}

private const uint SCARD_CLASS_VENDOR_DEFINED = 7;

public static UInt32 VENDOR_NAME { get { return SCardAttrValue(SCARD_CLASS_VENDOR_DEFINED, 0x100); } }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lReturn = GetAttribute((uint)hCard, VENDOR_NAME);
    lblData.Text = lReturn.ToString();    
}

public byte[] GetAttribute(uint m_hCard, UInt32 AttribId)
{
    byte[] attr = new byte[] { };// null;
    UInt32 attrLen = 0;
    attr.Initialize();
    int m_nLastError = ModWinsCard.SCardGetAttrib(m_hCard, AttribId, attr, out attrLen); //====    error 50 occurs here
    if (m_nLastError == 0)
    {
        if (attrLen != 0)
        {
            attr = new byte[attrLen];
            m_nLastError = ModWinsCard.SCardGetAttrib(m_hCard, AttribId, attr, out attrLen);
            if (m_nLastError != 0)
            {
                string msg = "SCardGetAttr error: " + m_nLastError;
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string msg = "SCardGetAttr error: " + m_nLastError;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
}
```

Why am I receiving an error using `SCardGetAttrib`, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately the command to return the serial number of a smart card is not standardized. Therefore it is unlikely that this can be fixed with another reader or reader driver. Get a manual of the card you use, look up the necessary command and send this APDU instead of queying the attribute. Alternatively, if you work in a project with a technical specification: take a look into the project specification; frequently there is stated, where the serial number shall be stored from which directly follows, how to get it.

Comment: @guidot - Re: *the command to return the serial number of a smart card is not standardized"*. I thought `SCARD_ATTR_VENDOR_IFD_SERIAL_NO` is the standard function to return the serial number. What does it return?

Comment: @jww It may work, if the OS recognises the card type and therefore knows the corresponding APDU. For an arbitrary card I would expect an error code otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too late but i think your AttribId value was wrong. You can look up AttribId value in the link below instead of converting from hexa to decimal by yourself

http://pyscard.sourceforge.net/epydoc/smartcard.scard.scard-module.html